# What's the difference between ( ' ' || false) and (false || ' ' ) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, logical-operators, logical-or

In [developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) website there are some examples to show different usage of logical OR operator, but this two examples got my attention, here they are :

```
o8 = ''    || false      // f || f returns false
o9 = false || ''         // f || f returns ""
```

Why this two, return different results? I expected both of them return false.

Comment: From that same page: "_If `expr1` can be converted to true, returns `expr1`; else, returns `expr2`_"

Comment: Boolean operators use so called "short circuit" -- for OR if the first operand is "truthy", the second is not evaluated, for AND if the first operand is "falsy" the second is not evaluated. But here in the first case the first one is "falsy", so it proceeds to the second one, and returns it. In the second case it does the same

Comment: note also that `a - b` and `b - a` may result in different values. The `||` operator imposes an order of evaluation.

Comment: in the first example `''` is coerced to a boolean to be evaluated by the `||`, in the second it is returned as a string.

Comment: @pilchard the `false` result in the first expression is the explicit `false` after the `||` operator, not the coerced string.

Comment: @Pointy I didn't say it wasn't, simply that the empty string was coerced in the first and not in the second

Comment: @pilchard you're right, I have not had enough coffee

Comment: Despite their common names (and most common use), && and | | in most dynamically-typed languages (NOT just Javascript) are NOT "logical and" and "logical or". They simply *select* one of their two operands to return. Which one is based on the truthiness or falsiness of the two arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See in the same page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR

> `expr1 || expr2`
>
> If `expr1` can be converted to `true`, returns `expr1`; else, returns `expr2`.

Answer (score 1):

All variables are [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), so during each evaluation, because the first operand (left side) is coalesced to a falsy value, the operand on the right side of the [`||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) will be used.